# Applying a css style to several patterns

Tags: html, css

How can I apply a CSS style block to several different classes? For instance, I have

```
<div class="foo">...</div>
<div class="bar">...</div>

...

.foo .bar ???    // This selector should apply to both classes
{
  font-size:50%;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```css
.foo, .bar
{
  font-size:50%;
  ...
}
```

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html#grouping

Answer (score 8):

use a comma:

```
.foo, .bar {
....
}
```

The converse, applying multiple classes to a single element is possible too:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .foo {
        }
        .bar {
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- 
        space separated list of classnames 
        to apply multiple css classes to a single element.
    -->
    <div class="foo bar">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```